# Binary Search Python

Tags: python, beginner, binary-search

Tried to make a binary search algorithm, how did I do?

```
def homogeneous_type(list1):
    i_list = iter(list1)
    listtype = type(next(i_list))
    return True if all(isinstance(x, listtype) for x in i_list) else False


def binSearch(list1, value):

    if not list1:
        raise ValueError("list is empty") 
    if not homogeneous_type(list1):
        raise ValueError("list must be one type")

    left = 0
    right = len(list1) - 1
    list1 = sorted(list1)

    while left <= right:

        midIndex, mod = divmod(left + right, 2)
        midIndex = midIndex + 1 if mod else midIndex

        if list1[midIndex] == value:
            return midIndex
        elif list1[midIndex] < value:
            left = midIndex + 1
        elif list1[midIndex] > value:
            right = midIndex - 1

    raise ValueError("value not in List")
```

Comment: Is the `homogenous_type` taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/13252348/1190388 ? If so, give credits as such!

Comment: Yeah it is I don't know how to credit it?

Comment: Normally, I put them in a docstring, like: `"""Taken from the discussion at: <link>..."""`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. There are no docstrings. What do `homogeneous_type` and `binSearch` do?
2. In Python we rarely need to insist that lists be homogeneous. It often makes sense to have heterogeneous lists, provided that all elements support the required operations, for example it can be reasonable to have a list containing a mixture of `int` and `float`.
3. Checking that the list is homogeneous requires looking at every value to check that it is the required type. But if you are going to look at every value, you don't gain anything by doing a binary search, you might as well just call `list1.index(value)`.
4. Similarly, sorting the list requires looking at every element, so again, there is no point in sorting and then doing a binary search. Skipping the sort and calling `list1.index(value)` would be faster.
5. The binary search code maintains a *closed* interval `left <= i <= right` that contains the index of the value being searched for. But maintaining a closed interval requires some complexity when computing the middle index:

   ```
   midIndex, mod = divmod(left + right, 2)
   midIndex = midIndex + 1 if mod else midIndex
   ```

   It would be simpler to maintain a *half-open* interval `left <= i < right` by starting with `right = len(list1)`. Then the computation of the midpoint is simple:

   ```
   midIndex = (left + right) // 2
   ```

   (In the half-open version of the code the loop condition needs to be `left < right` rather than `left <= right`, and you need to assign `right = midIndex` rather than `right = midIndex - 1`.)
6. On each iteration of the binary search loop there are *three* comparisons:

   ```
   list1[midIndex] == value:
   list1[midIndex] < value:
   list1[midIndex] > value:
   ```

   This can be reduced to *one* comparison per iteration, like this:

   ```
   left, right = 0, len(list1)
   while left < right:
       mid = (left + right) // 2
       if value < list1[mid]:
           right = mid
       else:
           left = mid + 1
   if left < len(list1) and value == list1[left]:
       return left
   else:
       raise ValueError("not found")
   ```

   Note that this version of the code works fine even if `list1` is the empty list, allowing you to remove the special case for `if not list:`.
7. Binary search is built into Python: see the [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) module.